# how does Neo4j create a property set not a duplicate values List for a dynamic property key

Tags: neo4j, cypher

For example

```
MATCH (p:Product{item_sku_id:'123'})
MERGE (p)-[:has_attribute]->(ea:ExAttrs)
with ea
match (ea) where none(x IN coalesce(ea.testAttr,[]) WHERE x = $ext_attr_value)
set ea.testAttr=coalesce(ea.testAttr+[$ext_attr_value], $ext_attr_value)
```

if I want to execute above cypher with csv file and I want to replace the `testAttr` as parameter. How should I implement it? Can anyone help me and many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
MATCH (p:Product{item_sku_id:'123'})
MERGE (p)-[:has_attribute]->(ea:ExAttrs)
with * where not $ext_attr_value IN ea.testAttr
set ea.testAttr=coalesce(ea.testAttr,[]) + $ext_attr_value
```